# ANDROID - Starting a Service from an Activity

Tags: android, opencv, android-service, video-capture

I'm developing an application that wants to grab some frame from the camera and perform marker detection, with the scope of calculating the relative position of the marker to the device.

To perform this, I've assumed to use a Service who runs in background and performs the operations (grabbing, detect, calc) that I need, using a new thread. After that, I've used the BoundService property to perform the dialogue between the MainActivity and that Service (following the official tutorial).

Now, I'm trying to run what I've done, but I have some problem: the code, after the successful initialization of OpenCV (async w/ manager), does nothing.

This is my Service:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service  {

//the external thread to perform
Thread processThread;

//binder to clients
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

//tags
String TAG = "processing Thread";
String TAG2 = "Service work";
String TAG3 ="RUN METHOD";

// parameters for Aruco detection
public CameraParameters mCamParam;
protected float markerSize = 0.195f;
    protected MarkerDetector mDetector;
    protected Vector<Marker> mDetectedMarkers;

//camera interaction object
private mobileCamera mCamera;
private Mat mFrame;

//Translation and Rotation matrixes vectors 
public Mat Tvec;
public Mat Rvec;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent _intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mBinder;
}

/**
 * class used for the client to access
 * @author andre_fromde
 *
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        BackgroundService getService() {
        //return this instance of background service so clients can call methods
        return BackgroundService.this;
    }
}

/*
 * Simply transform a mat in a string object.
 */
String Mat2String (Mat _mat) {
    return _mat.dump();
}

/**
 * Runnable object that encapsulate the RUN operations.
 */
Runnable marker_recognition = new Runnable() {
//Does the marker detection process.

public void run() {

    Log.i(TAG3, "called RUN method of the service.");
    while (true) {
      Log.i(TAG3, "Starting processing thread");

      synchronized (this) {
        //controls is a mCamera object is active
        if (mCamera == null) { 
        Log.i(TAG3, "exiting, no camera available.");
        break; //if not a mCamera, exit
        }

        //grab and retrieve the frame
        if (!mCamera.readFrame(mFrame)) {
            Log.e(TAG3, "mCamera.grab() failed");
            break; //if not a frame exit
        }

        //detection method
        Log.i(TAG3, "starting detection");
        mDetector.detect(mFrame, mDetectedMarkers, mCamParam, markerSize, mFrame);

        //get the marker in first position
        Log.i(TAG3, "getting first marker");
        Marker mMarker = mDetectedMarkers.get(0); 

        //gets the Tvec and Rvec data
         Log.i(TAG3, "getting TVEC and RVEC current values.");
        Tvec = mMarker.getTvec();
        Log.i(TAG3, "TVEC VALUES are:"+Tvec.dump());

        Rvec = mMarker.getRvec();
        Log.i(TAG3, "RVEC VALUES are:"+Rvec.dump());

      }

      Log.i(TAG3, "Ending processing thread");  

    }
 }

};

/**
 * Called when the service is started. 
 * Initialize the parameters needed.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(TAG2, "called Service onCreate. Start Aruco initialization");

    //Aruco parameters
     mCamParam = new CameraParameters();
     mCamParam.readFromXML(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/calibration/camera.xml");
     mDetector = new MarkerDetector();
     mDetectedMarkers = new Vector<Marker>();

     //this initialize the camera 
     Log.i(TAG2, "Init camera with 800x480 resolution.");
     mCamera.initializeCamera(800, 480);

     //creates the new thread with the runnable passed
     Log.i(TAG2, "Aruco done. Camera initialized. Init new Thread");
     processThread = new Thread(marker_recognition);

     //starts the thread just created
     Log.i(TAG2, "Starts the thread");
     processThread.start();
}

/**
 * This method is called when the service is started in the main activity
 */
@Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
      return START_STICKY;
   }

/** 
 * Release the camera when the service is destroyed
 * Stops the processThread
 */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Log.i(TAG2, "called service OnDestroy. Interrupt processThread and release camera res.");
    processThread.interrupt(); 
    mCamera.releaseCamera();
    Log.i(TAG2, "Successful release of Thread+camera");
}
```

}

This is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


public String TAG = "Project Marker Aruco";

//create a service
BackgroundService mBkgdService;
boolean mIsBound = false; //control for the binding of the service


/**
 * Dialogues with OpenCV manager for initialization of libraries
 */
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

/** 
 * Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() 
 * 
 */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

        // This is called when the connection with the service has been
        // established, giving us the service object we can use to
        // interact with the service.  Because we have bound to a explicit
        // service that we know is running in our own process, we can
        // cast its IBinder to a concrete class and directly access it.
        mBkgdService = ((BackgroundService.LocalBinder)service).getService();

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        // This is called when the connection with the service has been
        // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
        // Because it is running in our same process, we should never
        // see this happen.
        mBkgdService = null;
    }
};

/**
 * Establish the connection
 */
void doBindService() {
    // Establish a connection with the service.  We use an explicit
    // class name because we want a specific service implementation that
    // we know will be running in our own process (and thus won't be
    // supporting component replacement by other applications).
    bindService(new Intent(this, 
            BackgroundService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
}

/**
 * Stops the connection
 */
void doUnbindService() {
    if (mIsBound) {
        // Detach our existing connection.
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mIsBound = false;
    }
}


//Activity Lifecycle

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     //keeper of the screen on
     getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_6, this, mLoaderCallback);
     Log.i(TAG, "Called initAsync!");

     doBindService();
     Log.i(TAG, "Service on background started");
 }

 @Override
 public void onPause()
 {
     Log.i(TAG, "called onPause");
     super.onPause();
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() 
 { 
     Log.i(TAG, "called onDestroy");
     super.onDestroy();

     //calls the method that stopped connection with the service
     doUnbindService();
 }

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    Log.i(TAG, "called onResume");
    super.onResume();
}
```

The mobileCamera class performs camera interaction with OpenCV functions, using the VideoCapture class.

For information, this is the last log (if useful):

```
01-17 18:24:22.521: I/Project Marker Aruco(32256): called onCreate
01-17 18:24:23.652: D/dalvikvm(32256): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
01-17 18:24:26.635: I/Project Marker Aruco(32256): Called initAsync!
01-17 18:24:27.596: I/Project Marker Aruco(32256): Service on background started
01-17 18:24:27.606: I/Project Marker Aruco(32256): called onResume
01-17 18:24:27.636: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256): Service connection created
01-17 18:24:27.646: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256): Trying to get library path
01-17 18:24:27.746: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256): Trying to get library list
01-17 18:24:27.806: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256): Library list: ""
01-17 18:24:27.806: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256): First attempt to load libs
01-17 18:24:27.806: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256): Trying to init OpenCV libs
01-17 18:24:27.806: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256): Trying to load library /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libopencv_java.so
01-17 18:24:27.806: D/dalvikvm(32256): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libopencv_java.so 0x423d84e8
01-17 18:24:28.146: D/dalvikvm(32256): Added shared lib /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libopencv_java.so 0x423d84e8
01-17 18:24:28.146: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256): OpenCV libs init was ok!
01-17 18:24:28.146: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256): First attempt to load libs is OK
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256): General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.8 =====================================
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256):   Version control:               2.4.8
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256):   Platform:
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256):     Host:                        Linux 3.2.0-56-generic x86_64
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256):     Target:                      Linux 1 armv7-a
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256):     CMake:                           2.8.12
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256):     CMake generator:             Ninja
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256):     CMake build tool:            /usr/local/bin/ninja
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256):     Configuration:               Release
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256):   C/C++:
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256):     Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256):     C++ Compiler:                /opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++  (ver 4.6)
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256):     C++ flags (Release):

-----various parameters ---- (not reported)

01-17 18:24:28.176: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256): Init finished with status 0
01-17 18:24:28.176: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256): Unbind from service
01-17 18:24:28.176: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(32256): Calling using callback
01-17 18:24:28.176: I/Project Marker Aruco(32256): OpenCV loaded successfully
01-17 18:24:28.186: I/Choreographer(32256): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-17 18:24:28.256: D/libEGL(32256): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-17 18:24:28.276: D/libEGL(32256): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-17 18:24:28.276: D/libEGL(32256): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-17 18:24:28.296: D/OpenGLRenderer(32256): Enabling debug mode 0
01-17 18:24:36.885: I/Project Marker Aruco(32256): called onPause
01-17 18:24:37.525: I/Project Marker Aruco(32256): called onDestroy
```

Am I forgetting something?

thanks in advance for any tip.

Regards,

Andre

ps: if some other info is required just ask.